# How to use the Confluence API "get_all_pages_from_space"?

Tags: python, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to use the Confluence API "get_all_pages_from_space" to retrieve all pages (400 or so in total) in a Confluence space.

```py
# Get all pages from Space
# content_type can be 'page' or 'blogpost'. Defaults to 'page'
# expand is a comma separated list of properties to expand on the content.
# max limit is 100. For more you have to loop over start values.
confluence.get_all_pages_from_space(space, start=0, limit=100, status=None, expand=None, content_type='page')
```

The documentation for this API ([here](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html)) says that

> max limit is 100. For more you have to loop over start values.

I don't know what it means to **loop over the start values** in my Python code. I used this API to retrieve all the pages under a space, but it only returns the first 50 or so pages.

Is there anyone who have used this API? Please let me know how I can loop over the start values. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit late, but hopefully still might help:

```
def get_all_pages(confluence, space):
start = 0
limit = 100
_all_pages = []
while True:
    pages = confluence.get_all_pages_from_space(space, start, limit, status=None, expand=None, content_type='page')
    _all_pages = _all_pages + pages
    if len(pages) < limit:
        break
    start = start + limit
return _all_pages
```

Comment: I figured out a more clumsy "while" structure to loop over the start value, but the ``if len(pages) < limit: break" statement is really smart. Didn't thought of that! Thanks!